# Display API response as a card in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and so I'm a bit confused here; I have an API response that looks like this:

```json
{

      "title": "Bari Bari Densetsu",

      "id": "bari-bari-densetsu",

      "episode": "2",

      "episode_id": "bari-bari-densetsu-episode-2",

      "subOrdub": "SUB",

      "image_url": "https://gogocdn.net/cover/bari-bari-densetsu.png"
}
```

And I want it in the form of a card in html; how do I do it with JavaScript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I'm guessing you know this user as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77757548/519413.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display an API response as a card in HTML using JavaScript, you would typically fetch the API response, parse the JSON data, and then dynamically create HTML elements to display the data in the form of a card. Here is an example of how you could do it:

```js
// Suppose you have an API response stored in a variable
const apiResponse = {
  "title": "Bari Bari Densetsu",
  "id": "bari-bari-densetsu",
  "episode": "2",
  "episode_id": "bari-bari-densetsu-episode-2",
  "subOrDub": "SUB",
  "image_url": "https://gogocdn.net/cover/bari-bari-densetsu.png"
};

// Function to create a card element from the response
function createCardFromApiResponse(response) {
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  card.className = 'card';

  const image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = response.image_url;
  image.alt = response.title;
  image.className = 'card-img-top';

  const cardBody = document.createElement('div');
  cardBody.className = 'card-body';

  const title = document.createElement('h5');
  title.className = 'card-title';
  title.textContent = response.title;

  const episode = document.createElement('p');
  episode.className = 'card-text';
  episode.textContent = 'Episode: ' + response.episode;

  cardBody.appendChild(title);
  cardBody.appendChild(episode);
  card.appendChild(image);
  card.appendChild(cardBody);

  document.body.appendChild(card); // Assuming you want to add the card to the body of your page
}

// Call the function with the API response
createCardFromApiResponse(apiResponse);
```

This code assumes you are using bootstrap for styling since it uses bootstrap's card classes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const apiResponse = {
    "title": "Bari Bari Densetsu",
    "id": "bari-bari-densetsu",
    "episode": "2",
    "episode_id": "bari-bari-densetsu-episode-2",
    "subOrdub": "SUB",
    "image_url": "https://gogocdn.net/cover/bari-bari-densetsu.png"
  };

  const createCard = (data) => {
    const cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');

    card.innerHTML = `
      <h2>${data.title}</h2>
      <p>Episode: ${data.episode}</p>
      <p>Subtitle: ${data.subOrdub}</p>
      <img src="${data.image_url}" alt="${data.title}"/>
    `;

    cardContainer.appendChild(card);
  }

  createCard(apiResponse);
```

```css
.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

 .card img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Anime Episode Card</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="cardContainer"></div>
```